# Xamarin form expand programmatically listview height

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, resize, xamarin.forms

this is my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SetYourBudget.HomePage">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Label x:Name="lblImporto" Text="" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    <ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name ="list">
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="5" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#c1c1c1" x:Name="addLayout" Padding="10">
       //I remove thrash code
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I'm animating programmatically my `addLayout` to scroll down for the size of a `StackLayout` inside it. This is the code and it's working perfectly, he can scroll down and up to the original position:

```
    private async void BtnDropDown_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isVisible)
        {
            // hide
            // addSection is a section of the addLayout, not relevant in the operation it's only the size i need to scroll
            await addLayout.TranslateTo(0, addSection.Height + 10);
            imgDropDown.Source = Device.OnPlatform("btnMostra", "btnMostra", "btnMostra");
            isVisible= false;
        }
        else
        {
            //show
            await addLayout.TranslateTo(0, 0);
            imgDropDown.Source = Device.OnPlatform("btnNascondi", "btnNascondi", "btnNascondi");
            isVisible= true;
        }
    }
```

Now, my problem is the following: as you can see by the xaml, I have the `ListView` named `list` which is above the layout scrolling down.

When I scroll the lower layout, I want the list "growing"  to fill the size freed by the scroll animation.

I post an explicative image:

[image]

(obv I set some random datas couse it's just a text. My goal is just understand resizing)

thanks all and sorry for my not perfect english

Comment: were you able to figured out this issue, i am having the same problem.

Comment: @PrakashChennupati unfortunatly not. at the end we decided to go for a native solution instead of using crossplatform. maybe [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) might help you, sorry for not being able to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ListView x:Name="someName">
  <ListView.Footer> 
    <Label Text="some text" />
  </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```